# API to generate server-side static visualizations of sound clips

Tags: audio, processing, data-visualization

I'm developing an app that will pull in static PNG visualizations of sound clips (30 seconds max). The images will then act as the background image of the player / scrubber in the UI.

I'm looking for APIs / tools that would support the processing and visualization of sound clips on the back-end, generating and saving a quality PNG. I thought Processing might be an option, but am not yet sure if it has these specific capabilities (it's also not really designed to be server-side). Any and all suggestions would be great.

Related - if anyone is an expert in this, and can give me insight into the type of data that can be extracted and visualized from sound, that would also be great. Though, I am hoping by identifying possible tools or APIs, that information will become more clear.

Thank you.
Claudia

Comment: Certainly Processing is good at generating images, but what sort of data are you hoping to extract from the sound? If you're looking for more ideas on that, could you give an example of what you're imagining the output being for a given input?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! We are in the process of sketching ideas based on the data we think we can get ;) - so it's a bit of a chicken and egg issue. However, I think we want to be able to represent notes on the scale as well as the duration and intensity of the note over time - so a picture of the sound is created. As the playhead moves, it should align with a visual of that data at that moment in time.  This example is more than we need (3d probably not important - though could be interesting) - but an example of a style we like is: http://sandbox.aaronkoblin.com/projects/amsterdam/title.jpg

Comment: look at `minim` examples bundled with Processing.

Comment: i saw minim - it does look like it'll let me capture the audio data and save it out. then, use processing to generate an image based on that data? best plan? thanks so much!